# Which method to use when bulk-inserting data that needs to be transformed (Performance)

Tags: sql, datetime, bcp

I have been dealt the task of importing data from a file into an SQL Server database table daily. I researched different methods on doing bulk inserts and my idea was to use the `bcp` utility from the command line, by running a scheduled task daily.

My biggest problem is I don't know how to or if it is even possible to transform dates when importing data using bcp. For example, I have a date field in the format `dd.mm.yyyy` which I haven't been able to store as a SQL `datetime` type.

The file is updated daily (it currently has about 2 million rows or 255 MB of data), the way this works is a new file is created every day which contains all previous data and some new data at the end of the file. The first row of the file contains the headers for the data. The data that follows is semicolon separated and each row ends with a `\n`. The real file has 16 columns, so I have simplified it in an example:

**data.txt:**

```
NUMBER;START_DATE;END_DATE;GROUP_ID;IS_OPEN;TOTAL;
2262101;02.10.2010;01.11.2010;123456789012345678;0;268,75;
2291245;01.11.2010;01.12.2010;123456789012345678;0;67,25;
etc...
```

The format file I created is shown below (also an example with less columns). I am currently not importing the dates as SQLDATETIME because it doesn't seem possible due to the format (DD.MM.YYYY).

**format.fmt:**

```
10.0
4   
1       SQLINT     0 0  ""   1 Id        ""
2       SQLCHAR    0 4  ";"  2 Number    ""
3       SQLCHAR    0 50 ";"  3 StartDate Finnish_Swedish_CI_AS
4       SQLCHAR    0 50 ";"  4 EndDate   Finnish_Swedish_CI_AS
5       SQLCHAR    0 20 ";"  5 GroupId   Finnish_Swedish_CI_AS
6       SQLBIT     0 1  ";"  6 IsOpen    ""
7       SQLDECIMAL 0 18 "\n" 7 Total     ""
```

For the command i specify the table/db, the data file, the format file, -T = Trusted connection and -F = First row 2 to skip the header row.

**In cmd:**

```
bcp [database].[dbo].[table] in C:\...\data.txt -f C:\...\format.fmt -T -F 2
```

**The database table:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[table](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Number] [int] NOT NULL,
    [StartDate] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [EndDate] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [GroupId] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [IsOpen] [bit] NULL,
    [Total] [decimal](18, 2) NULL
```

My idea was to save the dates as strings but reading them using `CAST(StartDate as datetime)`, but that didn't seem to work with the `dd.mm.yyyy` format. I also tried executing `set dateformat dmy`.

So, I will need to import thousands of rows automatically into the database table daily and I need to transform the dates into datetime during this procedure. What is (performance wise) the best way to do this? Is it even possible to achieve it with bcp in an effective way?

Comment: Thousands of rows are nothing. Use any insert method you like. Also, this question is being asked over and over. You'll find all possible answers by searching.

Comment: The specific problem I had was the date format with dots as a delimiter. I'm not sure if the conversion that is needed will cause a performance hit when it's thousands of rows. Thanks for the valuable input.

Comment: I'd like to add that I'm not sure if I have to import the whole file each time or just the new rows. I read about one way, where you import all the data into a temporary table and replace the previous table with it. This is why asked, cause I don't know the best way to do what I want to do. This only has to work, it doesn't necessarily need to be the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you able to use SQL Server Integration Services?

SSIS would allow you to easily transform the data during import

[SSIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sqlserver/cc511477.aspx)

Comment: I'm sure that it could be arranged. I am currently reading about it, but thought I would post this question to see if there was a way to do it with bcp as I've been trying to make it work for a long while now :)

Comment: So i checked on the database server and there is a folder Integration Services with the choices: Data Profile Viewer, Deployment Wizard, Execute Package Utility and Project Conversion Wizard. I couldn't find SQL Server Business Intelligence Development Studio as a tutorial suggested: [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170057(v=sql.105))